# Unable to find a specification for `React-Core` depended upon by `UMReactNativeAdapter`

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Getting below error,

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Pre-downloading: `ExpoKit` from `http://github.com/expo/expo.git`, tag `ios/2.13.0`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
[!] Unable to find a specification for `React-Core` depended upon by `UMReactNativeAdapter`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I tried,

```
pod setup
pod install
pod install --repo-update
```

Also, I uninstalled/installed `cocoapods` again, but still getting above error.

Comment: Getting the same problem

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error for 'React-RCTFabric' as below.

```
Unable to find a specification for `React-RCTFabric` depended upon by `RNSVG`
```

I resolve this by enabling flag `fabric_enabled` in `Podfile`

```
:fabric_enabled => true,
```

Comment: I had the same error, and upgrading react-native-svg solved it.

Comment: To me was a matter of upgrading and enabling Fabric as mentioned above.

Answer (score 8):

you can change your UMReactNativeAdapter podspec file,

> s.dependency 'React-Core'

- change '-' to '/'

check out this for similar issue.

https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/402#issuecomment-513077800

Comment: Thanks! This helped! But isn't there a way to create a React-Core dependency in the poffile instead of changing several podspecs of packages?

Comment: try to downgrade library that used 'React-Core' , downgrade slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency `React-Core` is nothing more than the same React dependency being renamed by the developers.

You need to search for the version of UMReactNativeAdapter that list React as its dependency instead of React-Core

Answer (score -2):

I got tired of getting the same error again and again

Basically, what needs to be done is add manually to your `Podfile` the pod missing

`pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'`

And probably you will need to add some more pods this way, here is useful list of possible missing pods:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26310#issuecomment-534632566